# How to convert suds object to xml

Tags: xml, python-2.7, suds

Simply I need to convert an suds object to xml in string.

```
response = client.service.somemethod()
response_xml_string = response.as_xml() # something like this
```

Comment: you could be a little more explanatory or perhaps a little more research before to ask

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on totxt=True option in Client constructor.