# How to convert suds object to xml string

Tags: python, xml, soap, suds

This is a duplicate to this question:
[How to convert suds object to xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33303813/how-to-convert-suds-object-to-xml)

But the question has not been answered: "totxt" is not an attribute on the Client class. 
Unfortunately I lack of reputation to add comments. 
So I ask again:
Is there a way to convert a suds object to its xml?

I ask this because I already have a system that consumes wsdl files and sends data to a webservice. But now the customers want to alternatively store the XML as files (to import them later manually). So all I need are 2 methods for writing data: One writes to a webservice (implemented and tested), the other (not implemented yet) writes to files.
If only I could make something like this:
`xml_as_string = My_suds_object.to_xml()`

The following code is just an example and does not run. And it's not elegant. Doesn't matter. I hope you get the idea what I want to achieve:
I have the function "write_customer_obj_webservice" that works. Now I want to write the function "write_customer_obj_xml_file".

```
import suds

def get_customer_obj():
    wsdl_url = r'file:C:/somepathhere/Customer.wsdl'
    service_url = r'http://someiphere/Customer'
    c = suds.client.Client(wsdl_url, location=service_url)
    customer = c.factory.create("ns0:CustomerType")
    return customer

def write_customer_obj_webservice(customer):
    wsdl_url = r'file:C:/somepathhere/Customer.wsdl'
    service_url = r'http://someiphere/Customer'
    c = suds.client.Client(wsdl_url, location=service_url)
    response = c.service.save(someparameters, None, None, customer)
    return response

def write_customer_obj_xml_file(customer):
    output_filename = r'C\temp\testxml'
    # The following line is the problem. "to_xml" does not exist and I can't find a way to do it.
    xml = customer.to_xml()
    fo = open(output_filename, 'a')
    try:
        fo.write(xml)
    except:
        raise
    else:
        response = 'All ok'
    finally:
        fo.close()
    return response

# Get the customer object always from the wsdl.
customer = get_customer_obj()
# Since customer is an object, setting it's attributes is very easy. There are very complex objects in this system.
customer.name = "Doe J."
customer.age = 42
# Write the new customer to a webservice or store it in a file for later proccessing
if later_processing:
    response = write_customer_obj_xml_file(customer)
else:
    response = write_customer_obj_webservice(customer)
```

Comment: Do you have a code sample?

Comment: Code sample added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way that works for me. The trick is to create the Client with the option "nosend=True".

In the [documentation](https://jortel.fedorapeople.org/suds/doc/suds.options.Options-class.html) it says:

> **nosend** - Create the soap envelope but don't send. When specified, method invocation returns a RequestContext instead of sending it.

The RequestContext object has the attribute envelope. This is the XML as string. 
Some pseudo code to illustrate:

```
c = suds.client.Client(url, nosend=True)
customer = c.factory.create("ns0:CustomerType")
customer.name = "Doe J."
customer.age = 42
response = c.service.save(someparameters, None, None, customer)
print response.envelope # This prints the XML string that would have been sent.
```

Answer (score -1):

You have some issues in `write_customer_obj_xml_file` function:

Fix bad path:

```
output_filename = r'C:\temp\test.xml'
```

> The following line is the problem. "to_xml" does not exist and I can't find a way to do it.

What's the type of customer? `type(customer)`?

```
xml = customer.to_xml()  # to be continued...
```

Why mode='a'? ('a' => append, 'w' => create + write)

Use a `with` statement (file context manager).

```
with open(output_filename, 'w') as fo:
    fo.write(xml)
```

Don't need to return a response string: use an exception manager. The exception to catch can be [EnvironmentError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.EnvironmentError).

### Analyse

The following call:

```
customer = c.factory.create("ns0:CustomerType")
```

Construct a `CustomerType` on the fly, and return a `CustomerType` instance `customer`.

I think you can introspect your `customer` object, try the following:

```
vars(customer)  # display the object attributes
help(customer)  # display an extensive help about your instance
```

Another way is to try the WSDL URLs by hands, and see the XML results.
You may obtain the full description of your `CustomerType` object.

### And then?

Then, with the attributes list, you can create your own XML. Use an XML template and fill it with the object attributes.

You may also found the magic function (`to_xml`) which do the job for you. But, not sure the XML format matches your need.

Comment: I know. It is only pseudocode to illustrate the problem. The path is not the problem, nor is it mode 'a' or the with syntax or error handling. The type of customer is suds.sudsobject.CustomerType

Comment: I improve my response to explain why it is difficult to make a simple answer, and give you my analyse…

Answer (score -1):

```
client = Client(url)
client.factory.create('somename')

# The last XML request by client
client.last_sent()
# The last XML response from Web Service
client.last_received()
```